# How to add multiple parameters to the URL at once

Tags: javascript, html

Currently, if you add `?dc=bananas` or `?dc=apples` to the end of the URL, it shows that content, but how can I make it so that I can do up to 10? For example`?dc=bananas+apples+oranges` and it would show all content for the ID's added?

Also, is it possible to set it up so that I don't have a separate div for each one? Can this be done dynamically with one div checking for parameters in the URL?

HTML:

```
<div id="default-content" class="dynamic-content">
  This is the default content
</div>
<!-- Dynamic Section 1 -->
<div id="apples" class="dynamic-content">
  I like apples
</div>
<!-- Dynamic Section 2 -->
<div id="oranges" class="dynamic-content">
  I like oranges
</div>
<!-- Dynamic Section 3 -->
<div id="bananas" class="dynamic-content">
  I like bananas
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.dynamic-content {
    display:none;
}
```

JS:

```
(function($){
    // Parse the URL parameter
    function getParameterByName(name, url) {
        if (!url) {
            url = location.href.split("?dc=").slice(-1)[0];
        } 
        return url;
    }
    // Give the parameter a variable name
    var dynamicContent = getParameterByName('dc');
 
     $(document).ready(function() {
 
        // Check if the URL parameter is apples
        if (dynamicContent == 'apples') {
            $('#apples').show();
        } 
        // Check if the URL parameter is oranges
        else if (dynamicContent == 'oranges') {
            $('#oranges').show();
        } 
        // Check if the URL parameter is bananas
        else if (dynamicContent == 'bananas') {
            $('#bananas').show();
        } 
        // Check if the URL parmeter is empty or not defined, display default content
        else {
            $('#default-content').show();
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Data:

```
const myProducts = [{
  "productCode": "ABC",
  "productNumber": "1467-6281",
  "Name": "Example Item",
  "Price": "1.975",
  "Quantity": "4"
},
{
  "productCode": "HJK",
  "productNumber": "1111-9809",
  "Name": "Example Item 2",
  "Price": "2.975",
  "Quantity": "14"
},
{
  "productCode": "AOP",
  "productNumber": "8792-3890",
  "Name": "Example Item 3",
  "Price": "3.975",
  "Quantity": "8"
}]
```

Comment: window.location.search.split("+");

Comment: How does your data correspond to your example JS? (Since there are no apples, oranges and bananas there)

Comment: Apple, oranges, and bananas are just placeholders. From the data, the productCode would replace these. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can have multiple parameters with the same name:

```
...?dc=bananas&dc=apples&dc=oranges
```

Which also allows you to easily create a `div` for each one:

```
// Use the URLSearchParams interface to get an array of
// all values for the parameter you want to query.
const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
let dynamicContent = urlParams.getAll('dc');

// For each value in the array, create and insert
// a new element.
for (let dc of dynamicContent)
{
    let newSection = document.createElement('div');
    newSection.id = dc;
    newSection.classList.add('dynamic-content');
    newSection.innerText = 'I like ' + dc;
    document.body.appendChild(newSection);
}

// Show or hide the default depending on if values exist.
if (dynamicContent.length) {
    document.querySelector('.default-content').style.display = 'none';
}
else {
    document.querySelector('.default-content').style.display = 'block';
}
```

The [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) interface is widely supported outside of Internet Explorer.

Comment: Would this replace any parts that I have or is it an addition?

Comment: This would replace everything in your JS file and all the dynamic `div`s you defined in your HTML.

Answer (score 0):

```
(function($) {

  // Parse the URL parameter
  function getParameterByName(name, url) {
    return url ?? location.href.split(`?${name}=`)[1];
  }

  $(document).ready(function() {
    const keys = getParameterByName('dc')?.split('+');
    let dynamicContent;

    // For each entry, check whether it correspondents to a div

    if (keys)
      keys.forEach(key => {
        if (key == 'apples')
          dynamicContent = $('#apples');
        else if (key == 'oranges')
          dynamicContent = $('#oranges');
        else if (key == 'bananas')
          dynamicContent = $('#bananas');
        if (dynamicContent)
          dynamicContent.show();
      });

    // If during the entire loop no element has been found, show the default one

    if (!dynamicContent)
      $('#default-content').show();
  })
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. What if I have a lot of different keys in a separate JSON file with the data. Would they all have to be listed?

Comment: No, instead of using the big `if else` clause you would try looking your data up using the `key` variable using `data[key]` for example. My answer only literally does what you asked: it finds the different words separated by `+` from your URL parameter. For a more dynamic approach we should know your data.

Comment: Hey, I just added an example of the data, would you mind showing how I can look up the data using the key variable if there's a lot of products within the JSON file?

Answer (score 0):

Side point: `query-string` library is great to convert a JS object to an url query string and get the raw query string to convert it to a JS object.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/query-string